# I want to know can I get path PromiseValue data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I call `action.word()`
and `console.log(action.word())`
I want path **"I LOVE U"** . Can I do?

[image: image description here]

Comment: No, you need to do the logging (or whatever you actually want to do with the result) asynchronously.

Comment: Hook the promise's resolution and access the `text` property on the object you receive. See the linked question's answers, particularly in the places where they *consume* promises (using `.then`/`.catch` or, within an `async` function, `await`).